# R: how to output predicted probabilities from logistic regression in RSSL

Tags: r, machine-learning, logistic-regression, prediction

```
library(RSSL)
set.seed(1)
df <- generateSlicedCookie(1000,expected=FALSE) %>% 
  add_missinglabels_mar(Class~.,0.98)
df_test <- generateSlicedCookie(1000,expected=FALSE)


class_lr <- LogisticRegression(Class~.,df,lambda = 0.01)
class_lr_self <- SelfLearning(Class~., df, method=LogisticRegression)
```

Here, `class_lr` is a logistic regression model. To obtain its predicted probabilities, I can call (thanks to the answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60406638/r-how-to-output-prediction-probabilities-with-classification-models)):

```
log(posterior(class_lr, df_test))
```

The second model, `class_lr_self` is a logistic regression model with a self-learning wrapper. Is there a way to output the predicted probabilities from `class_lr_self`?

Running `predict(class_lr_self, newdata = df_test)` only gives me the labels.

I've tried the following, but there is no `posterior` method for `SelfLearning` as there is for `LogisticRegression`.

```
> log(posterior(class_lr_self, df_test))
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘posterior’ for signature ‘"SelfLearning"’
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no method for this class, if you check [it](https://github.com/jkrijthe/RSSL/blob/master/R/SelfLearning.R):

```
setMethod("predict", signature(object="SelfLearning"), function(object,newdata,...) {
  ModelVariables <- PreProcessingPredict(object@modelform,newdata,y=NULL,scaling=object@scaling,intercept=FALSE,classnames=object@classnames)
  X<-ModelVariables$X

  return(predict(object@model,X,...))
```

}

We just have a new function that returns the posterior:

```
func =  function(object,newdata,...) {
  ModelVariables <- PreProcessingPredict(object@modelform,newdata,y=NULL,scaling=object@scaling,intercept=FALSE,classnames=object@classnames)
  X<-ModelVariables$X

  return(posterior(object@model,X,...))
}
```

And you do:

```
log(func(class_lr_self, df_test))
```

Or you set a posterior method for this:

```
setMethod("posterior", signature(object="SelfLearning"), function(object,newdata,...) {
  ModelVariables <- PreProcessingPredict(object@modelform,newdata,y=NULL,scaling=object@scaling,intercept=FALSE,classnames=object@classnames)
  X<-ModelVariables$X

  return(posterior(object@model,X,...))
})

log(posterior(class_lr_self, df_test))
```